# Remove _ (underscore) when converting an object to array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, naming-conventions

According to the Zend framework naming conventions private variables should start with _ (underscore). But it cause problems when converting an object to an array (casting). The array element keys start with "_". How can I remove the underscore while converting an object to array?

For example

```
class Book {
     private _name;
     private _price;
}
```

will be converted to

```
array('_name' => 'abc', '_price' => '100')
```

I want to remove the '_' in array element keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you want something like this:

```
//because of variable scope this method must be in the class where the private propeties are.
public function toArray() {
        $vars = get_object_vars($this);
        $array = array();
        foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
            $array[ltrim($key, '_')] = $value;
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

This will allow you to call `->toArray()` in your model, view or controller.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat tough without an exact example but this should be close. Basically loops through, finds elements that start with _, removes them and inserts an underscore-less element to the array

```
$arr = array(
  'foo1' => 'bar1',
  '_foo2' => 'bar2',
  '_foo3' => 'bar3'
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
     if (substr($key,0,1) == '_') {
         unset($arr[$key]);
         $arr[substr($key,1)] = $val;
     }
}
```

After this, `$arr` will look like

```
Array
(
    [foo1] => bar1
    [foo2] => bar2
    [foo3] => bar3
)
```